# Why don't keydown or keyup work in this example of SendMessage?

Tags: c#, dllimport, sendmessage

I'm using this code

```
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 256;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 257;
    const int WM_CHAR = 258;

    public static void SendKeys(string message){
        int foregroundWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint remoteThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindowHandle, 0);
        uint currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

        //AttachTrheadInput is needed so we can get the handle of a focused window in another app
        AttachThreadInput(remoteThreadId, currentThreadId, true);
        //Get the handle of a focused window
        int focused = GetFocus();
        //Now detach since we got the focused handle
        AttachThreadInput(remoteThreadId, currentThreadId, false);
        foreach (char c in message)
        {
            //SendMessage(focused, WM_CHAR, (int)c, null);
            SendMessage(focused, WM_KEYDOWN, 65, null);
            SendMessage(focused, WM_KEYUP, 66, null);
            SendMessage(focused, WM_CHAR, 67, null);
        }
    }
```

And when I test it (with Notepad being active, for example), only the letter C prints, so only WM_CHAR is working - why?

Comment: You want to send incomplete events and expect it to capture all the input as if it were valid?

Comment: Uh - what?  You're implying that I'm missing something ("incomplete events") but it isn't clear to me what I'm missing.

Comment: Okay I'll rephrase to avoid assumptions, what is your desired output given the code written? What is it *not* doing that you expect it to do?

Comment: I had expected it to write "ABC".  I originally was only using WM_KEYUP, but nothing happened, and when I tried using another code example that had WM_CHAR, I got curious, so I tried all three. My desired end result is to send some text to the foreground window.  Using WM_CHAR works, but many examples I've seen only use WM_KEYUP, which doesn't work for me...

Comment: Okay well briefly in this scenario you are at the mercy of the developer of the application you are targeting as to which messages in the windows message loop that they actually handle in their application. So unfortunately it isn't as black and white as saying `WM_CHAR` works but `xxx` does not because the application in question may completely discard certain messages it doesn't care about or has decided not to handle. Are you specifically targeting notepad to attempt to write data or is this a more broad attempt to send keystrokes to different applications?

Comment: It's a broad attempt to send keystrokes to different applications.

Comment: You cannot reliably simulate input by sending or posting messages.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  My exact application is this:  I have a barcode scanner and I am attempting to send the scanned barcode to several differnt apps that all need to receive the scanned string.  There is a commercially available solution, which I am trying to duplicate.  I would assume the commercially available solution is using API calls.

Answer (score -1):

First, understand that questions asking how to send keyboard messages are asked very often. I assume you have not invested much time looking for previous answers. Second, understand that beginners often mistakenly think that sending keyboard messages is the easiest and most effective solution. The truth is that it is usualy not the easiest and is not the most effective and not the most reliable.

If you are going to work with Windows messages like that, then learn to use Spy++. If you do not know what that is, then please invest a minute by familiarizing yourself with the tools available in the VS Tools menu.

A likely easier, more efective and reliable solution usually is to use the WM_GETTEXT and WM_SETTEXT messages. And anticipating future questions, to push a button in another application send a BN_CLICKED notification to the **parent** of the button. You can use Spy++ to get many more answers to questions of messages.

Comment: Sam, you unconstructively stated, "I assume you have not invested much time looking for previous answers." - I've spent most of today reading about and debugging this thing.  And even if that were not the case, your implicit criticism only makes me more frustrated than I already am.  However, thanks for the pointer to Spy++ - I'll check that out.

Comment: I have seen this question so often that I know you would find ample help if you looked for previous answers and for relevant articles. Spending most of a day on the problem is not the same. People that volunteer to help others prefer to help people that first look for previous answers and for relevant articles.

Comment: Ok Sam Hobbs with a 59 reputation score - I do not want to get into a flame war, but I will point out the irony of you lecturing me - with a higher reputation score - about "people that volunteer to help others".  I'm not interested in any more judgments from you - please don't feel obligated to help me any more.

Comment: Note that no one else is helping here and I assume because they think the help you need exists elsewhere and is easy to find.